# jstree get highlight node

Tags: jstree

Most of the questions in jstree are about getting the selected node (and related id, etc).  My current code for getting the selected node is:

```
viewerObj.bind("select_node.jstree", 
    function (e, data) { 
        var nodeId = jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id;
        //alert(nodeId);
        var date = new Date();
        ...
);
```

But what I really want is not the selected node necessarily, but the highlight node (and parent id) so that I could capture the "create_node" event when it is triggered.  How do I do that?  I can't seem to find any code that does this correctly.

Here's the image of what the UI looks like:[image: Select node (top) and highlighted node (bottom)]

I want to know how to grab "models".  The select_node event capture the node that is selected (or "admin") in this case.

---

Update:

This does it:

`.bind("hover_node.jstree",
        function(e, data){
            var nodeId = jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id;
        }
    );`

It capture the hover event and grabs the id associated with the node that was last hovered.

Comment: Looks like I found some information on jstree-hovered, but for some reason I can't get it to work correctly to capture the hovered node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

This does it:

```
.bind("hover_node.jstree", function(e, data){
       var nodeId = jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id; 
});
```

It capture the hover event and grabs the id associated with the node that was last hovered.